# 'Int' is not convertible to 'Range<Int>' when checking property value

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, core-data

I have a subclass of a `NSManagedObject`, when checking if the property value of an instance is nil with a control flow statement I get the following error;

> 'Int' is not convertible to 'Range

What I am trying to do is check if the property value has a value if so then create an instance of that value, (the value type is another subclass of a NSManagaedObject).

**Subclass:**

```
class Items: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var index: NSNumber
@NSManaged var title: String
@NSManaged var folder: Folder

}
```

Error is In my table view when checking the value - I fetch all Items objects and cast to an array to display in the tableview:

**Error**

```
  var folder: Folder!

  //Error occurs here 
  if self.items[indexPath!.row].folder != nil {  
       folder = self.items[indexPath!.row].folder
  }
```

I am not sure why this is occurring and how to resolve the issue, has anybody got any solutions to what I am trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I use obj-c, not Swift.  What's a Folder object? I can't find any documentation on it.

Without knowing more about that object, maybe try:

```
if self.items[indexPath!.row].folder {
    folder = self.items[indexPath!.row].folder
}
```

If folder is anything other than nil, that should work.  You'll have to verify that what you consider a nil folder does not get you inside of that if statement, though. Without knowing what a Folder is, I have no clue how it's treated as a condition.

Comment: I mentioned Item has a property call Folder which is another NSManagedObject. So it may have a relation to another NSManagedObject, if it does then I am trying to get an instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by adding the value to an instance then checking if the instance had a value of nil. Still unsure why I was receiving the original error.

```
 var folder: Folder!

 shelf = items[indexPath!.row].folder

 if folder != nil { println"ok" }
```